# Can I store this user information in NSUserDeafaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, pci-compliance

### **Overview:**

I have an IOS app that allows a user to create an order from menu items and then check out that order using a credit card.

I am aware that you cannot store a users credit card information and that this can only be stored with a registered authority i.e.: the credit card gateway (somewhere that is PCI compliant).

### **The Question:**

I need to store a users first name, last name, mobile number and email address, so these fields can be autofilled on a future order. Just to be clear the name and number are not in any way associated with the credit card or payment method, that is a separate field and is handled differently. This is just user information for the actual order that is handled through our servers.

Could I store these pieces of information in NSUserDefaults so when the user goes to checkout in the future these fields are autofilled?

Comment: Yes, you can go ahead with NSUserDefaults, but database is better option while you are going store this much amount of data.

And in NSUserDefaults you just have to store that data like this.

{
data:[
User1 detail
],[
User2 detail
]
}

and so on.

Comment: Yes, its not bad to use NSUserDefaults for this, however using sqlite is more reliable for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely store the information in NSUserDefaults but as others have pointing out a database like SQLITE will be a better option. In the future your app might grow and might want history of items user has purchased or shown interest in. At that point you don't want to store collections in NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

One more option for you is using Core data